# Life insurance for security guards

Tags: criminal-law, california

From [here](https://www.guardianbooth.com/security-guard-shot/amp/), death rate of security guards is 1/1000 per year. Of the armed, professional guards its maybe 10x higher.

An average life insurance policy is $100 per month for a 30 year old, with a about a 0.001% monthly risk of death. That means, scaled for risk of death, a security guard would need 100x more or $10,000 a month life insurance. This is obviously far excess of their wage.

Since security guards are basically irrational and dont adequately value their lives, is it fraud for them to take out a life insurance policy? Not that they would, but if a security company took out policies for security guards would it basically either be impossible or a fraud conspiracy, given their risk of death is so under priced?

Comment: Not relevant to the law but a correction on the death rate.  The article you link to cites a risk of 8 in 10,000 but it cites the source of that number this Bloomberg article https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2015-dangerous-jobs/ which gives the rate as 7.63 per 100,000.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.bls.gov/iif/oshwc/osh/os/osar0009.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjf0evFxqbtAhV1FjQIHQPDAqIQFjALegQIThAB&usg=AOvVaw0bhoNkbu5dlMCE-2Y3Z2ou&cshid=1606611591460 bls says 100 deaths out of a million, but that includes part time.

Comment: From that source, "the rate of fatal injuries to security guards was 9.4 fatalities per 100,000 workers in 2007" which is basically consistent with the 7.63 per 100,000 from Bloomberg.  That's a base rate of ~1 in 10,000 not ~1 in 1,000.   Your "10x higher" for professional guards also seems like a suspect assumption- if it was anything like that high, I'd expect the sources to at least mention that fact.  It appears the baseline rate is consistent with the 0.001% monthly risk of death you quote (0.012% annual rate is 1.2 in 10,000).

Comment: Yeah but night guards in high crime cities should be 100x deader

Comment: Why "should" they be anything? Insurance doesn't care what should happen, only what actually does and what can be estimated.

Comment: But it can be estimated from bls statistics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as a person applying for life insurance accurately discloses his or her occupation (and other relevant personal characteristics, such as age and health) in accordance with local law and the company's application form, there is no fraud.

The company may or may not charge a higher rate for people with high-risk jobs. That is a business decision for the insurance company, although it may be limited by law or regulation in a particular jurisdiction.

Comment: It isn't fraud if the person taking insurance has made LL necessary disclosures. The fact that the insurance risk is sold on to others doesn't magically change the facts or the law applicable to them.